# Creating a pivot table from Geonames based on isPreferredName column in AlternateNames table

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, geonames

I am currently working on a query from the citiesXXXX table in the geonames DB which displays the alternate names of places in other languages, i.e. 'en', 'de', 'fr' etc.

While I managed to create a pivot table by JOINing the AlternateNames table, I am having a hard time generating a condition if e.g. there are two records for one city for the 'de' language, and one of these is marked with TRUE in the 'isPreferredName' column.

My current query:

```
SELECT 
    c.geonameid,
    c.name,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN an.isoLanguage = '' THEN an.alternateName
    END) AS 'ALT',
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN an.isoLanguage = 'en' THEN an.alternateName
    END) AS 'EN',
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN an.isoLanguage = 'fr' THEN an.alternateName
    END) AS 'FR',
    c.country
FROM
    cities15000 c
JOIN
    alternatenames an USING (geonameid)
GROUP BY c.name
ORDER BY c.country , c.name
```

Ideally, I would like to fetch the record marked as 'isPreferredName' for each language, if there is one, but otherwise simply the record corresponding to the language.

I have been looking for similar questions, here and elsewhere, but all questions on nested conditions deal with numerical values, to be fed into one formula, rather than another. I don't need any operation to be performed on the output.

As requested, here is the SHOW CREATE TABLE for both tables involved:

```
| alternatenames |
CREATE TABLE `alternatenames` (
  `alternatenameid` int NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID alternate name',
  `geonameid` bigint DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'GeoName ID',
  `isoLanguage` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ISO639 2-3 char, ''post''=Postal Code, ''iata'',''icao'' & faac=Airport Code, ''fr_1793'',  ''abbr''=abbreviation, ''link''=URL, ''wkdt''=wikidata',
  `alternateName` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Alt name or variant',
  `isPreferredName` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Alternate name is an official/preferred name',
  `isShortName` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Short name like ''California'' for ''State of California',
  `isColloquial` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Colloquial or slang term. Example: ''Big Apple'' for ''New York''',
  `isHistoric` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Historic and was used in the past. Example ''Bombay'' for ''Mumbai''',
  PRIMARY KEY (`alternatenameid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

```
| cities15000 | 
CREATE TABLE `cities15000` (
  `geonameid` bigint NOT NULL COMMENT 'Integer id of record in geonames database',
  `name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Name of geographical point',
  `asciiname` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Name of geographical point in plain ASCII characters',
  `alternatenames` varchar(10000) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Comma separated, ASCII names automatically transliterated, convenience attribute from alternatename table',
  `latitude` decimal(10,7) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Latitude in decimal degrees (wgs84)',
  `longitude` decimal(10,7) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Longitude in decimal degrees (wgs84)',
  `fclass` char(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'http://www.geonames.org/export/codes.html (featureCodes.txt)',
  `fcode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'http://www.geonames.org/export/codes.html (featureCodes.txt)',
  `country` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ISO-3166 2-letter country code',
  `cc2` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Alternate country codes, comma separated, ISO-3166 2-letter country code',
  `admin1` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1st Level Admin Division - FIPS for US (admin1Codes.txt)',
  `admin2` varchar(80) DEFAULT '' COMMENT '2nd Level Admin Division - County in US (admin2Codes.txt',
  `admin3` varchar(20) DEFAULT '' COMMENT '3rd Level Admin Division',
  `admin4` varchar(20) DEFAULT '' COMMENT '4th Level Admin Division',
  `population` bigint DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Population (8 Byte INT)',
  `elevation` int DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Digital elevation model (srtm3)',
  `gtopo30` int DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Digital elevation model (gtopo30)',
  `timezone` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'IANA timezone id (timeZone.txt)',
  `moddate` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Date of last modification in yyyy-MM-dd format',
  PRIMARY KEY (`geonameid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

(N.B. There are different tables beginning with 'cities' in the DB, but all have an identical structure.)

Comment: It would be helpful if you would use a free online mysql editor like dbfiddle to clearly illustrate what your data looks like. The 'isPreferredName' column you have mentioned is not available on your clear so it is ambigious as to what you intend to achieve.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: Thanks. Have added what I hope is what you will need.